# Check if data equals something on Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When the user registers, I send this to the database, along with the users information: `firstLogin: "false"`

When the user signs in, I want to check if it's their first time doing that, so I want to check if the firstLogin equals "false".

I tried doing it this way but it's not working.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then( () =>{
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user.firstLogin === "false"){
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).update({
        firstLogin: "true"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `creationTime` and `lastSignInTime` of `user.metadata` are equal. If they are the same, this is a new user.

```
if (user.metadata.creationTime === user.metadata.lastSignInTime) {
  // this is a new user
}
```

Alternatively if you call `signInWithPopup`, you can use:

```
if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
  // this is a new user
}
```

See:

- [`UserMetadata` reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.UserMetadata)
- [Firebase Google Authentication - Check if User Logs in for first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273940/firebase-google-authentication-check-if-user-logs-in-for-first-time)
- [Firebase Auth check if new user on Facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982151/firebase-auth-check-if-new-user-on-facebook-login)
- [`signInWithPopup` reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithPopup)